# AverageIf based on one criteria OR another in one column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can anyone explain why this does not work?

```
=AVERAGEIF(Data!C:C,{"Monday","Tuesday"},Data!L:L)
```

I want the average of the L column where there is Monday OR Tuesday in the C column. It gives the result of average Monday only.

Answer (score 3):

I can provide an alternative using AVERAGE & IF as an Array Formula.

Most likely the reason why it does not work is because you are passing an array to it {"Monday", "Tuesday"} but the function on its own is not operating as an Array Formula resulting in processing only the first element of the array i.e. "Monday"

E.g. Try this `=ROW(A1:A4)` This is expected to return 1,2,3,4 but it returns 1 as it's not an array formula. Converting this to an array formula still returns 1 the first element as there's nothing to process the array. Now wrap this in SUM e.g. `=SUM(ROW(A1:A4))`and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER from within the formula bar to convert this to an array formula. Now it correctly returns 10 same as  `=SUM(1,2,3,4)`

You should also avoid Average of Average as it might lead to erroneous results. e.g. Average(1,2,3) is not same as Average(Average(1,2), Average(3))

Use this array formula to get the desired result.

```
=AVERAGE(IF(Data!C:C={"Monday","Tuesday"},Data!L:L))
```

Press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER from within the formula bar to convert this formula to an array formula.  Formula shall enclose itself in curly braces now.

Without array formula this will lead to erroneous results.

[image]

Comment: That is excellent. Thank you. =AVERAGE(IF(Data!C:C={"Monday","Tuesday"},Data!L:L))

Answer (score 0):

Your `AVERAGEIF` function is returning an array.  You then need to average the resultant array:

```
=AVERAGE(AVERAGEIF(Data!C:C,{"Monday","Tuesday"},Data!L:L))
```

However, that does not really provide the average of everything with either Monday or Tuesday unless Monday and Tuesday have exactly the same number of entries.  In other words it is the average of the average of Mon;Tue

If Monday and Tuesday do not have the same number of entries, and you want that accounted for in the average, you need to do something like (not tested)

=SUM(SUMIF(Data!C:C,{"Monday","Tuesday"},Data!L:L))/SUM(COUNTIF(Data!C:C,{"Monday","Tuesday"}))